# CSS dropdown closes too early

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

My dropdown works fine, except it closes before i can move mouse top of last link in it.

CSS

```
    nav {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
}

nav .links {
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-align: center;
}

nav .links a {
    color: #666666;
    text-decoration: none;
    word-spacing: normal;
}

nav .links a:visited {
    color: #666666;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav .links a:hover { 
    color: #383838;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav .links a:active {
    color: #666666;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul {
    position:relative;
    list-style:none;
    color: #666666;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

nav li{
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

nav ul li ul { 
    display: none; 
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 0.5em;
    line-height: 1.2;
} 

ul li:hover ul {
    display: block; 
}
```

HTML

```
<nav>
<div class="links">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php?sivu=etusivu.php">ETUSIVU</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?sivu=historia.php">HENKILÖKUVA JA HISTORIA</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?sivu=viewAlbum.php&amp;album=1">KORISTEKERAMIIKKA</a></li>
        <li>GALLERIA
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php?sivu=viewAlbum.php&album=2">Keramiikkaveistokset</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?sivu=viewAlbum.php&album=4">Keramiikka - kuparityöt</a></li>
                <!--Next link is the one where dropdown closes before mouse reaches it-->
                <li><a href="index.php?sivu=viewAlbum.php&album=5">Krisu testi</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tested it with Chrome and FF. CSS is not top skill for me and i think this should work but obviously im wrong :)

I would appreciate help with this greatly, thanks.

**EDIT**
I changed nav ul li ul as...

```
    nav ul li ul { 
    z-index: 1;
    display: none; 
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 0.5em;

}
```

and now it works just fine. So basically i just added z-index there.

There is an image right below dropdows, not sure is it possible that it messes this one? Atleast z-index did help...

Comment: I can't see the issue you describe. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexChariz/jdsmqf6j/)

Comment: Hi Alex and thanks for notice.

Comment: So i suppose it work as it suppose?

Comment: I got it working in my project with z-index. Would you please read my edited original post?